# Sending serial terminal keystrokes from Python

Tags: python, terminal, rs485

I am trying to simulate keystrokes from a python script to a serial terminal. Apparently typing the character "a" and sending the keypress event are two different things.

I tried adopting this guide, but it didn't seem to work: 
https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-bluefruit-ez-key-diy-bluetooth-hid-keyboard/sending-keys-via-serial

Further, I tried reading the serial ports directly and seemingly the keypress "a" sends out "O\x00" which led me to think that if I simply sent "\x4F\x00" this would work. Perhaps there is a timing issue that I am running into...

```
import serial
import time

def writeChar(port, char, bVerify = True):
  port.flush()
  port.write("\xFD")
  if (char.isupper()):
    # Shift left
    write("\x02")
  else:
   port.write("\x00")
   port.write("\x00")
   port.write(Keys[char.upper()])
   port.write("\x00")
   port.write("\x00")
   port.write("\x00")
   port.write("\x00")
   port.write("\x00")

   if (char != "KEY_NONE"):
     time.sleep(.1)
     writeChar(port, "KEY_NONE", False)

   if (bVerify):
     inChar = port.read()

def writeChar2(port, char):
  port.flush()
  port.write(Keys2[char]+'\x00')
```

Neither of these attempts seemed to work. Keys['A'] = \x04. Keys2['a'] = \x4F

The thing that seemed the most surprising to me was that I couldn't find anyone that has already done this. It seems like automating keystrokes/commands from a script would be very useful.

What could I be missing?

Comment: *"seemingly the keypress "a" sends out "O\x00""* How do you know? What's on the other end of your serial link? Just for fun, does it react to telnet escape `^]` or other commands prefixed by CTRL/^? Do you receive what you send if you connect TX and RX on the transmitting side - maybe via a low value resistor for safety? Just some stuff to try if you're out of ideas.

Comment: I was using Python's Serial package to read raw bytes. As a sanity check, I'm now using two RS485 / USB adapters connected through a gender changer.
Looking further, "a" is 0b01100001 and "O" is 01001111. Seemingly this could be an issue of not crossing TX and RX lines over. I'll pull out my soldering iron!

Comment: *"I'm now using two RS485 / USB adapters"* And that allows you to see what you're sending (one receives, the other transmits)? I think what constitutes a key-press is entirely up to the thing receiving your key presses (which you don't mention at all, as far as I can tell).

Comment: After more investigation, I realized that one of the USB adapters I was using was RS232. Apparently it was working just well enough to make it seem like everything was fine when it actually wasn't. When I got the correct USB adapter, everything went very well.

Always verify the assumptions! Thanks for the help

Comment: That's one subtle bug! Glad you figured it out :)